# Ionic 2: Native Google Maps VS Google Maps API in App

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, ionic2

The problem of displaying the **gray block** when the map is loaded.

I tried both versions of the maps.

**Native maps** is not very suitable for many reasons, but it is loaded without gray blocks.

**Google Maps API** is completely suitable, but there is a problem when loading the map. Is it possible to somehow map the cache so that it is displayed as a native map?

Video links:

1) **Native maps** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3-nogB56zm8

2) **Maps API** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P3STDooVkk

Answer (score 1):

I understand you are using the Google Maps JavaScript API with Ionic 2. If so, 
have a look at the following feature request in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38110237

Feel free to star the feature request to express your interest and subscribe to further notifications from Google.